Best way to fix the traces and patch on the PCB coating - zebra stripe to go on top
I was trying to fix this kitchen precision scale for my girlfriend and I noticed some segments of the LCD were simply not working. After disassembly, there you go.
How can I fix the traces, considering the LCD zebra stripe is to go on top?
Any irregular patch on the PCB will most likely cause connection issues with other points of contact on the zebra stripe. I tried to look up tutorials on the internet but this no so lucky. I could use nail polish or UV resin for the patch on top, but what about the traces?


Unless this particular kitchen scale is very dear to your GF's heart, I'd suggest that although possible, repairing it is uneconomical (unless you value your time at less then $1/hour).

Lots of videos on youtube showing the techniques available to replace corroded traces.  Typically you glue something conductive like foil or wire over the gaps in the trace or pad and solder the ends to reconnect the trace, but there are many methods you could use.

You don't need to fix the green solder resist coating. You do need to get rid of the corrosion. Start simple. Perhaps with just a cotton swab. Then work your way up. Maybe add water (distilled if handy). Then maybe alcohol if the water is not able to dissolve the corrosion. Finally you might try a mild non conducting abrasive like baking soda. Do not use conductive abrasives like steal wool. Keep the static electricity minimal by not doing this in a dry place (like on a cold day). It would be great if you had static mitigating work-mats and wrist-straps. The object is not to damage the copper traces.

I does look like the copper traces are damaged. But we will know more after the corrosion is removed. If they are damaged it might be very difficult to fix. Usually people bridge short trace breaks with solder and longer breaks with wire. I doubt either will work here as the flexible zebra conductor likely works best if pressed against a flat surface. Any solder would create an irregular surface. Making it a challenge to create good contact for all traces.

The copper traces are clearly worn away on pads 1 and 4 - if you have copper tape just cut a section, stick it where the pad was, and scratch off some solder resist from the connecting trace then solder over the join.
If you don't have copper tape lying around, super glue down some foil, it's not as good but should do the job. Good Luck!
